# Replacing backslashes

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm trying to replace `/` and `\` with `//`:

```
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\mysite/bla/bla';
str_replace(array("\/", "\\"), array("\/\/", "\/\/"), $path);
```

but it doesn't work:(

I get `C:\\/wamp\\/www\mysite/bla/bla` ...

Comment: All the answers are the same, but you don't need to have an array in your `replacement` argument if they are the same. ie, this will work: `$path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), '//', $path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to escape the forward slash, so it is interfering with the pattern match.

Also, `str_replace` returns the replacement, it is not a byRef function so you'll need to store the return in a variable ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)).

See it happen: http://codepad.org/CNr8P79m

```
<?php
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\mysite/bla/bla';
$path = str_replace(array("/", "\\"), array("//", "//"), $path);
echo $path;
// output: C://wamp//www//mysite//bla//bla

?>
```

Comment: No, I don't. The backslash needs to be escaped, the forward slash does not. The example code I pasted is accurate using the details you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape `/` and you need to assign the return value of `str_replace` to a variable:

```
$path = str_replace(array("/", "\\"), array("//", "//"), $path);
```

Comment: I did assign it to a var. And it doesn't work if I don't escape it, I get parse errors

Comment: There's something else wrong, then. Please see my answer (which is the same as this one), there is a sample script included. As you can see, no syntax error results. This answer is factually correct and does not warrant a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to normalize paths then I can recommend replacing all directory separators by `/` as this doesn't interfere with escaping and works on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape slashes only backslashes.

```
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\mysite/bla/bla';
$path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), array('//', '//'), $path);
```

Comment: FYI: A single quote or a double quote has absolutely no effect on the results of this script.